# The name: `Algebra' over a field/ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra

An algebra over a field $F$ is a vector space over $F$, equipped with bilinear multiplication. i.e. $(v_1 + v_2) \cdot v_3 = v_1 \cdot v_3 + v_2 \cdot v_3$.

Why have our maths ancestors overloaded the name 'algebra' to also mean this structure? Is it just coincidental that this name has stuck?

In the theorems that I have seen, only examples of algebras are used. Has any theorem been proven using just the fact that the underlying structure is an algebra?

Comment: Are you asking if there are any theorems about algebras, or in your case rings which are vector spaces over a field? Because there are plenty.

Comment: @IanColey I meant to ask if there are any theorems about algebras. Not for specific algebras like the complex numbers, or the polynomials. But theorems which which go like "If A is an algebra, then ...".

According to Wikipedia, [link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field[link], an algebra is almost a ring which is a vector space over a field, except that it need not be associative or have an identity. Do algebras have any easy properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was once a persian mathematician that wrote an important book on rules of computations. His name, "al-Khwarizmi" was made eternal in "algorithm", the book title containing "ḥisāb al-jabr wa-l-muqābala" gave the word "algebra".

In the renaissance, algebra was everything that surpassed simple accountancy. Most prominently, solving polynomial equations and computations with roots.

Until the middle-end of the 19th century, mathematics was largely without structures. The idea of vector spaces and even of the set of real numbers started only in that period. The systematic use of structures is a side effect of axiomatic mathematics. Thus it is natural that the structure of polynomials, which were called "(entire (rational)) algebraic functions" at that time, is called "algebra". Because you need polynomials and their arithmetic to do "algebra".

That this was then generalized to the definition that you gave is due to the economy of words, why invent a new word when you can just re-purpose the name of the most prominent example.

To pinpoint this more precisely, one would have to find out when "Matrizenkalkül" or "matrix calculus" became "matrix algebra" and when the structure of infinitesimal symmetries was first named "Lie algebra", and if it had a different name before.